# r code removing words containing @

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I want to replace all words containing the symbol @ with a specific word. I am used gsub and therefore am applying it to a character vector. The issue that keeps occuring is that when I use:

```
gsub(".*@.*", "email", data)
```

all of the text in that portion of the character vector gets deleted.

There are multiple different emails all with different lengths so I can't set the characters prior and characters after to a specific number.

Any suggestions?

I've done my fair share of reading about regex but everything I tried failed.

Here's an example:

`data <- c("This is an example. Here is my email: emailaddress@help.com. Thank you")`

`data <- gsub(".*@.*", "email", data)`

it returns 
[1] "email"

when I want 
[1] "This is an example. Here is my email: email. Thank you"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider including a *small* [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can better understand and more easily answer your question.

Comment: `.*` matches all characters, perhaps you want `[^\s]*@[^\s]*`

Comment: If you just want to replace the "@" sign, just use `gsub("@", "email", data) ` otherwise anything else you match with the pattern will be replaced as well.

Comment: @user3772674 When adding new information, it's better to edit your original question than to add additional information in the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following..

```
gsub('\\S+@\\S+', 'email', data)
```

**Explanation**:

`\S` matches any *non-whitespace* character. So here we match for any *non-whitespace* character (`1` or more times) preceded by `@` followed by any *non-whitespace* character (`1` or more times)

Answer (score 3):

To replace strings with an embedded "@" in R, you can use (translaiting @Fabricator's pattern to R)

```
data <- c("This is an example. Here is my email: emailaddress@help.com")
gsub("[^\\s]*@[^\\s]*", "email", data, perl=T) 
data
# [1] "This is an example. Here is my email: email"
```

Comment: You don't need `perl=T` here =)